# How to read Window Spy re ControlClick

Tags: click

I want AHK to click on the "Publish" button in WordPress. I take it that I can use ControlClick, but Help says get the info from Window Spy. Window Spy gives me the same NN class regardless of whether the cursor is over the button or not. I can't post a screenshot, but it says:

> > > > > > > > > (Now under Mouse cursor)<<<<<<<<

ClassNN: Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND2
Text:
Color:    0xA2&223

(The color is indeed blue-green).

Thanks.